# Magento 2.1 deploy static content production mode fails

Tags: deploy

after spending some hours with this issue I now dare to ask. I think I have overseen something stupid. After switching in production mode my, I run static content deploy command wich runs without any errors. But after that admin and frontend are missing all styles. Seems although deploy command works, static files are not written, pub/static is missing files and console error says require.config failed to load. strangely, I seem to have the opposite problem of those who have in the developer mode problems with the symlinks, because the developer mode with the symlinks works wonderfully, the symlinks are written without problems in pub / static.

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Some issues can arise if you are running the console commands as root, when the fle system should be www-data owned. Make sure your files have the correct user:group or run a chown command over them to be sure. That has happened to me before.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty stupid! But for everyone who is as stupid as I am, here is the simple solution: One must not forget its language. A simple setup: static-content: deploy is not enough, only the default language is provided. For example, explicitly setup: static-content: deploy en_US de_DE to fully create front and backend files. Perhaps I should have read the documentation more often and better, perhaps also the Magento developers should have made such a point more clearly.